# Delete .txt files from current folder BATCH

Tags: batch-file, delete-file

I have a test folder with a .bat that unzips any zip files in the current folder.  That works great.  I am looking to delete all .txt files from the current folder. (The files I just unzipped) How can I only delete .txt files that in the current folder?

This is what I last tried, but nothing happened.

```
for /f "delims==" %%F in ('dir  /b /s  *.txt') do echo %%F
```

Comment: You said current folder. You are also deleting from sub folders as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try passing `del` instead of `echo` to your for iteration, like this:

```
for /f "delims==" %%F in ('dir  /b /s  *.txt') do (del %%F)
```

And there you go!

Comment: The equals symbol is a valid character for a file name.  Just use "delims=". Better yet just use a regular FOR command or FOR /R.

Comment: No problem! Glad it helped you!